# Aggregating Grafana to the Most Current Data

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to aggregate memory usage data from Prometheus into a table in Grafana, but I only want the most recent memory usage stats. Currently, I'm getting the same service's memory usage repeated over and over.

I've tried reducing the Time Range, but that didn't seem to have an impact.

[image: Example Grafana Table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Options** tab,

Set **Table Transform** to *Time series aggregration*.

Then set **Columns** to *Current*.

[image]

Comment: There's also the "Instant" checkbox just below your query. You want that checked, as you're only interested in the instant (i.e. last value) not the whole timeseries. It's also more efficient than querying the whole history (for whatever your dashboard's time range is) and only using one value.

Comment: Sweet @AlinSînpălean! With the instant option checked, the query is a more [efficient one](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/v5.2.5/public/app/plugins/datasource/prometheus/datasource.ts#L148).